# Can't load local img in react using require

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to render local images inside a map loop.

I have seen in many posts that I should use `require`

```
const urlBase = './../../assets/';
const CompList = (props) => {
    return props.skills.map((elm, index) => {
        console.log(`${urlBase}${elm.imageName}`)
        return <Chip
            key={`comp-${index}`}
            avatar={<Avatar alt="Angular" src={require(`${urlBase}${elm.imageName}`)} />}
            label={elm.techno}
        />
    })
}
```

But I'm getting this error

> Cannot find module './../../assets/Angular.png'

The app was generated using `create-react-app`

Comment: This should work, please re-create the bug. https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way -

```
const imageToShow = require('../path-to-the-file.extension');

<Chip
  key={`comp-${index}`}
  avatar={<Avatar alt="Angular" src={imageToShow} />}
  label={elm.techno}
  />
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: relative path to the project works better and in his case the urlBase and other stuff make it more complicated for bundlers by involving file system directories for the path. Just a Opinion.